# What's the most efficient way to record details on page hits

Tags: php, mysql, csv, analytics

We have a microsite being advertised in a national newspaper as part of the deal they require the following information for *every* page served to be provided as CSV or similar:

- Time of page served
- Date of page served
- Full URL served
- Session ID

I really have no idea of the number of visitors expected but it could be fairly high, so the question is; what is the best and most efficient way to do this?

The site is static but I can use PHP or whatever. Am I likely to run into trouble just adding these details to a MySQL database each time a page is served?

Comment: What about Google Analytics or Piwik?

Comment: Was my first thought too to be honest but can I get this sort of detail using either of those?

Comment: No, you can't get Session ID with GA. Btw what do you want to measure from it?

Comment: I don't want to measure anything, it's a requirement from an advertising partner. I think GA might be out of the picture then, thanks.

Comment: Sorry Jamie, but GA is out of the picture but the script that you would start to write is in picture?? :o

Comment: Sorry fabrik I don't really understand your last comment.

Comment: Ok, GA isn't the holy grail but i think it's far more reliable than a script that you'll try to rake here.

Comment: More reliable than just writing to database? The consensus from the answers below is that doing so would be efficient but is probably overkill for my requirement, so I'm not sure how it would be unreliable. I have no idea how to do what I need to do with GA, feel free to suggest a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Well, first of all, i have no idea why do you want to store required data not already in desired format but store in in SQL first and then convert to CSV.**

Especially if you site is static, so, you will need to employ PHP somehow to do it.
but okay, even if you're gonna employ PHP, using sql instead of CSV still looks nonsense to me.

Your web-server most likely already logs almost everything you need, and with minor tuning will be able to log session id too.

So, if your server happen to be Apache, most efficient solution would be just custom access log, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

it's gonna be like

```
LogFormat "\"%t\", \"%f\", \"%{PHPSESSID}C\"" csv
CustomLog logs/access_log csv
```

and just set up your cron to send this log by email every day

Please note that conditional logging should be probably used too, to limit logging to html pages only. I never used it nor tested but according to docs it could be

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/$" logable
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.html$" logable
CustomLog logs/access_log csv env=logable
```

Comment: If you're not going to do any analysis of the data then this should be the best solution. You might want to also filter out non-page hits like image requests etc.

Comment: `%{PHPSESSID}` cannot be used in that log format directive. It would have to be extracted from `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` first. RewriteCond can do that, but won't work in conjunction with mod_log.

Comment: Ok well I agree, I was just suggesting a method I knew well. Grabbing logs would be far more efficient and since that was the primary question, this is the answer.

Comment: @Jamie just note that this method will grab every url requested. to limit it to just html pages see Conditional logging here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html

Comment: Nice solution; it is important to point out that `\"%{PHPSESSID}C\"` will log only cookie-based session IDs. The `url.php?PHPSESSID=xyz` cookieless fallback will not be logged - however the session ID will be in the logged URL in that case

Answer (score 1):

Have a common php file included on every page you need to track and within the script record details to MySQL as you yourself suggest. MySQL is scalable and powerful and will be able to handle it, as it powers some of the internet's busiest sytems.

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining this data via MySQL table would be efficient, but might not be necessary, strictly speaking, depending on the load you will be getting.

Alternatively, you could consider just using something more lightweight like sqlite.

http://www.sqlite.org/

http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php

It's nice and effective and requires little setup or tweaking, and database resides in a file on your server!

MongoDB might be another option that will scale much better and allow you to avoid SQL all together!

I guess what I'm getting is this, while MySQL will perform this task very well, you can certainly get away with something different and more simplistic. I do want to qualify this, though, and say that sqlite may have some issues once you get into large amounts of activity!

Comment: Ok great, that's exactly what I was after. I had thought of SQLite actually but I'm not sure it's available on the sever, the same might be the case with mongoDB but I'll check both out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're getting over million users you shouldn't have to worry...

To be honest you can do several ways of monitoring the hits. That way you have several different types of proof!

Use google analytics, which is a bit of javascript code provided by google. This won't increase the load on your server by any significant amount.

Create you're own code to pick up that data... do you need help in detecting each piece of information?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Google Analytics.

BUT, if you really need to know: if the site is already in PHP then there's no reason why you can't insert into a db (or add to a CSV file?) these details. Why do you want to track the session id?

Here's some sample code for the db option:

```
<?php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (`time`, `date`, `url`, `session`) VALUES (CURTIME(), CURDATE(), " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ", " . $_SESSION['id'] . ");
```

Comment: Thanks, tracking the session id is just a requirement I've been given. Why do you think I should use GA? I've not really used GA much aside from the basics so I have no idea how I would go about doing so.

Comment: see @fabrik's answer regarding how to implement. GA will show how many people have been accessing what pages (or your site overall) via handy tables and line charts, with details such as where in the world (based on IP) that person is viewing your site, how long a person stayed on your site, and whole host of other useful information. It even allows export of data in pdf, xml and csv.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a database for that. Concurrent accesses is what they are made for. But actually this reads more like a task for log files. You are not querying those results ever again, you are just collecting them.

Usually it is as simple as (assuming you need no value escaping):

```
$csv = "$time,$date,$url,$session_id" . "\n";
file_put_contents("hit.log", $csv, FILE_APPEND);
```

File_put_contents is atomic, which is what you want for log files to not lose entries. But for many concurrent accesses it is not optimal; processes might block each other. Thus you would need another cheat:

```
$csv = ...
$id = rand(1,10);
file_put_contents("hit{$id}.csv", $csv, FILE_APPEND);
```

This distributes the logs across multiple files; rand() is enough to even it out. While you now need to merge multiple files again, you at least have it in the right format already.

Comment: I was considering writing to file but was worried about concurrent access. I may give this a look.

Comment: Apache uses a similar approach to handle logs. Albeit they have a spooler process/thread to handle the log writing. That's why hardly anyone needs `mod_log_sql`.

Answer (score 1):

- Sign in to [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/settings/home) with a Google Account
- Click Add website profile
- Follow the instructions

All you need to do is inserting a tiny JS snippet to the bottom of your page:

Example from Stackoverflow's source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq=_gaq||[];_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-5620270-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function(){
        var ga=document.createElement('script');
        ga.type='text/javascript';
        ga.async=true;
        ga.src='http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,s);
    })();
    _qoptions={qacct:"p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc"};
</script>
```

*Note: Do not copy this snippet directly, GA will generate your code automatically.*

Comment: GA will count clients with JS enabled (and no GA disabled) only

Comment: Thanks I'm aware of how to add GA I just don't know how I can then use it to get the required info into a CSV. Using logs or even a database seems more efficient (and accurate as Col. Shrapnel mentions).

Comment: Since i'm not paid by Google i should say choose from the other alternatives written here :)